# Hinting at alphanumeric character in input patterns?

Tags: input, textbox

When hinting at the format for strict data entry in a textbox on a website (`<input type="text"/>`), I normally use `A` to represent alphabetic characters, and `9` for numeric characters.

Therefore `AA999` would signify that things like `AB123` or `xy221` would be accepted.

But is there a standard way to state that you can enter an alphanumeric character (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in regex)?

Comment: Do you have a more concrete example to share that we could base ourselves on?

Comment: Is there any restrictions at all on the data in the textbox? Min/max length? Any types of character disallowed?

Comment: Also, is there a use case for this input? UK Royal Mail's postcodes have a complex rule set, sometimes alpha, sometimes numeric, sometimes eitehr. [Their lookup tool](http://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode) provides realtime feedback as you type, without giving the user specific instructions to follow.

Comment: @TimFitzGerald, sorry, but I'm not sure what examples I can give you.  I'm simply asking if there is a way to easily convey the fact that an input has a particular format, and a particular character can either be a letter or a number.  I'm obviously not asking this correctly, because it's not a difficult concept in my mind!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a place holder attribute to say "e.g. 9876 5432 1098 7654"

I generally find it's better to use a realistic example rather than a symbolic one. It's more quickly understood.

For a british license plate "e.g. AB01 CDE" is more quickly understood than "XX## XXX".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say there is a standard way, Another way you can do it is a validation system like they do for passwords.

Comment: It not so much a validation thing, but a way of telling the user the correct format of the information that requires entering *before* they submit the form.  I normally do this by putting static text next to the input such as `[dd/mm/yyyy]` for dates, or `[AA999]` for specific.  it's just how to easily tell them that a character can be *either* `A` or `9` that I'm struggling with

Comment: @freefaller oh well then you can just give examples

Answer (score 0):

If a textfield accepts any character, then the best way to indicate this is to put **nothing at all** by the textfield. That's the default, normal state for textfields: accepting any text (it's called free text for a reason). Any special hints will just end up being distracting and confusing more than it will help the user.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was asking for. His request was about setting expectation for a strict format field.

Comment: I'm not sure it's what the OP was asking for either; but I'm not sure it's *not* what the OP was asking for. I'm hoping they clarify, so we can be sure what kind of answer would be useful.